# Oracle error building table from 2 foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I'm in the process of building a database and have already successfully created 2 primary key tables however when I try to bring them in as 2 foreign keys to another table I am running into a

> "CLIENTID" invalid identifier

Unsure how to resolve as not the best at this.

```
CREATE TABLE Booking(
  BookingID number(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Client_FK FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES client (ClientID),
  CONSTRAINT Course_FK FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES course (CourseID),
  CONSTRAINT Booking_PK PRIMARY KEY (ClientID, CourseID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the columns on which your primary key and foreign keys are created; you need something like the following, to be edited with the right type for your columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking(
  BookingID number(10) NOT NULL,
  ClientId number,  -- missing
  CourseID number,  -- missing
  CONSTRAINT Client_FK FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES client (ClientID),
  CONSTRAINT Course_FK FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES course (CourseID),
  CONSTRAINT Booking_PK PRIMARY KEY (ClientID, CourseID)
)
```